# When adding new jar files to lib folder getting class not found exception of previous module lib in studio

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

I have an app that has as minSdkVersion API 16, When I added new jar files **activation, additionnal, mail, itextpdf** for sending pdf file throw email. Its throwing exception below for previously added module library:

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.inbridge.avakaash-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.inbridge.avakaash-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]**

If I remove these new jar files then its working fine...

this is my gradle:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.inbridge.avakaash"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':library')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile project(':payUMoneysdk')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-win-4.4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'

    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.5.9.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

This is my settings.gradle

```
include ':library'
include ':payUMoneysdk'
include ':avakaash'
```

Please any one help me to resolve this error...

Comment: Please any one give solution for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `multiDexEnabled true` in not enough when you're targeting devices older than 5.0 Lollipop. If you want to support KitKat and older then in addition to this flag, you also have to deploy the secondary dexes make your main `Application` class, as explained [in the official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

There are multiple ways to do this:

1. You can make your your `Application` class extend from `MultiDexApplication`

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
   ```
2. You can add the following lines to your `Application` class:

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
     MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());
     super.onCreate(arguments);
   }
   ```
3. If you don't use a custom `Application` class, you can enable it via the AndroidManifest.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.example.app">
     <application
         ...
         android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
     </application>
   </manifest>
   ```